# Windows form controls error with MetroFramework

Tags: c#

Whenever I drag a metroframework control onto a form window it appears in the bottom left corner of another window instead of on the form itself.

It only happens with metro controls and not regular ones. How to make the controls appear only on the form window?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `Form` to a `MetroForm`.

Before anything else, you must have a `REFERENCE` and it should be like this:

```
using MetroFramework;
```

or optionally add this:

```
using MetroFramework.Forms;
```

For this change this:

```
public partial class yourForm1 : Form
```

To this:

```
public partial class yourForm1 : MetroForm
```

Among many others there is a nice tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mM4fLnRDVto) that goes through the whole process:

- Downloading
- Compiling
- Copying the 3 DLLs you need
- Creating a new project
- Changing the form type (!)
- Adding references
- Adding the using clause
- Adding controls..